# Entity Framwork. Generic entity method to add to any set type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generic-programming

I am trying to figure out how to make a generic entity Object. I have about 5 different entity types which share common properties.

I have created an abstract class TableBase & Interfaces that allow me to address entities' parent & children:

```
    public interface IHasChildren
{
    IEnumerable<object> Children { get; }
}

public interface IHasParent{
    Object Parent { get; }
}

public abstract class TblBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  ....
      properties such as 
      int ParentID
      int COID
      bool IsSelected
      bool IsExpanded
  ....
 }

//tblLine is one of my 5 entity type classes which build up a hierarchy
       public partial class tblLine : TblBase, IHasChildren, IHasParent
        {
            public virtual ObservableCollection<tblGroup> tblGroups { get; set; }
            public virtual tblProject tblProject { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is my code at the moment:

```
    public static bool AddNode(ProjectEntities DBContext, LocalUser User, object ParentEntity)
    {
        var BaseEntity = (TblBase)ParentEntity;
        var ChildType = ((IHasChildren)ParentEntity).Children.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

        Object NewNode = new tblLine
        {
            ParentID = BaseEntity.ID,
            COID = User.ID,
            IsSelected = true,
            IsExpanded = true
        } as object;

         DBContext.Set(ChildType).Add(NewNode);

        return true;
    }
```

The problem here as you can see, NewNode is type specific, and will only let me add this object to its set type.
I need to achieve some way of adding to the set with an object type it would accept.

Comment: why don't you add generic parameter to AddNode like `AddNode<T>`. in that case, you can pass the required type.

Comment: I have tried. Look at the result below

Comment: Can you please post how tblLine is declared?

Comment: I have added it to the question @user1672994

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making AddNode() a generic method?

```
public static bool AddNode<T>(ProjectEntities DBContext, LocalUser User, T ParentEntity) where T:TblBase, new()
{
    var BaseEntity = (TblBase)ParentEntity;
    var ChildType = ((IHasChildren)ParentEntity).Children.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

    T NewNode = new T
    {
        ParentID = BaseEntity.ID,
        COID = User.ID,
        IsSelected = true,
        IsExpanded = true
    };

     DBContext.Set<T>().Add(NewNode);
//may want to call DBContext.SaveChanges() here if no further actions to be taken
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It won't let me make a new T hey. Says that it does not have a new constraint

Comment: I get an exception that the only the specific type entity can be added to Set<T>. And a TblBase object cannot be added to it.

Comment: Sorry then I don't know